# Can you use Google Analytics to see how many Android Tablets are visiting your website?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, tablet, user-agent

I would like to see how many visits my website is getting from Android Tablets.

Google Analytics can show you iPad, iPhone and iPod visits, but when it comes to the multiple Android devices out there all you can see is 'Android', no difference between phones or tablets!

If Google Analytics won't help, is there a way to use some kind of user-agent string to detect and track Android tablet visits.

Comment: Is this issue that you just want to know who is visiting your site, or do you want to serve them different content (e.g. customised stylesheet)? This might help people answer your question.

Comment: I want to see how many Android Tablet visitors are looking at our website.

Comment: ok, that wasn't clear from the original question.

Comment: No worries, welcome to StackOverflow! Most of us are pretty helpful (here am I helping in a subject I know little about), but there are some tags where people downvote vigorously if they think the question isn't clear. Have a look at the FAQ on how to construct a good question.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll check out those FAQ's. I will edit my original question as well if that's advisable on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the NEW interface for Google Analytics, then go to Visitors > Mobile > Devices.

It shows you a very detailed list of all the devices visiting your site, along with photos of what they look like!

Answer (score 1):

With the Google Analytics Mobile; on any page click the "Advanced Segments" button. Check the "Tablet Traffic" option and click apply. Now all your analytics data will be calculated only using tablet devices. You can remove this criteria by clicking the X button next to "Tablet Traffic" label. (It's under the "Advanced Segments" button)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an advanced segment with Android OS and resolution conditions. I beleive tablets have greater screen resolutions than smartphones. Here' the [advanced segmentation](http://services.google.com/analytics/breeze/en/advanced_segmentation/index.html) tutorial.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay, that sounds like a good solution. I also found another solution using the new Google Analytics interface. See my answer below. Best, Jay